# fetching address from a XML object to a variable in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to create a sales order script that pulls the XML from ebay and then creates a sales order according to the information.

Its working when I use the following code to save the address from the XML to addressbook on customer record and then use it as the shipping address using the below code

```
var xmlobj = nlapiStringToXML(xmlstring);
var customerInternalID = findCustomerByEbayID(nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//BuyerUserID'));
if (!customerInternalID){
            var customer = nlapiCreateRecord('customer');
            customer.setFieldValue('subsidiary', SUBSIDIARY);
            customer.setFieldValue('isperson', 'T');
            var emailAddr = nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//Buyer/Email');
            if (emailAddr.indexOf("@") === -1 ){
                emailAddr = nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//Buyer/StaticAlias');
            }
            if (emailAddr.indexOf("@") === -1 ){
                emailAddr = null;
            }
            customer.setFieldValue('email', emailAddr);
            customer.setFieldValue('custentity_ebay_user_id', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//BuyerUserID'));
            customer.setFieldValue('firstname', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//UserFirstName'));
            customer.setFieldValue('lastname', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//UserLastName'));
            customer.setFieldValue('phone', nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Phone').substring(0, 12));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addressee', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Name'));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr1', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Street1'));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr2', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Street2'));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr3', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Street3'));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'city', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/CityName'));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'state', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/StateOrProvince'));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'zip', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/PostalCode'));
            customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'country', 1, nlapiSelectValue(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress/Country'));

            customer.setFieldValue('custentity11', 'T');
            customerInternalID = nlapiSubmitRecord(customer, true, true);
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'SUBMIT', 'Customer submitted with internal ID' + customerInternalID);
        }

        var customerRec = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', customerInternalID);  
        var defaultAddress = customerRec.getLineItemValues('addressbook', 'id', 1);
```

but when I try to use the address from XML directly as shipping address using the below code, I'm ending up having no address on the sales order

```
    var defaultAddress = nlapiSelectValues(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress');
```

Answer (score 0):

`nlapiSelectValues` selects the text value of a node.

If you are just trying to simplify your code then what you want is something like:

```
var defaultAdress = nlapiSelectNode(xmlobj, '/GetOrdersResponse/OrderArray/Order['+(i+1)+']//ShippingAddress');
customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addressee', 1, nlapiSelectValue(defaultAdress , 'Name'));
...
customer.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'defaultshipping', 1, 'T'); // don't forget this
...
var soRec = nlapiTransformRecord('customer', customerInternalID, 'salesorder'); 
// the new sales order has the default shipping address as the ship to address

//however in case you have an existing customer and just want to use the supplied address:
    var shippingAddr = soRec.getSubrecord({fieldId:'shippingaddress'});
    var setShip = function(fld, val){
        shippingAddr.setValue({fieldId:fld, value:val});
    };

    var getP = function(fld){
      return nlapiSelectValue(defaultAdress , fld);
    };


    setShip('addressee', getP('Name'));
    setShip('addr1', getP('Street1'));
    setShip('addr2', getP('Street2'));
    setShip('city', getP('CityName'));
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I actually want to use the address from XML as the shipping address rather than the one from customer record even if the customer is already there in the NetSuite because that could be a different address than the one on the customer record (eg: when customer orders for someone)

Comment: In SS2.0 you use the `shippingaddress` subrecord. See updated example